# retrieving data from table ordering based on search value??/

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a table named products

```
---------------------------------------
 | productid   |  productname          |                           
 |-------------------------------------|
 |      1      | orange juice          |
 |      2      | mutton biriyani       |
 |      3      | mango juice           |
 |      4      | fish biriyani         |
 |      5      | chicken biriyani      |
 |             |                       |
 ---------------------------------------
```

I have a search value named `'biriyani'`.

I have to retrieve all the products from the table in such a way that the first set of values should be that match with the search value and next the remaining datas

**sample output :**

```
chicken biriyani

fish biriyani

mutton biriyani

orange juice

mango juice
```

Comment: I think you should use CONTAINS or like operate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `ORDER BY` clause which has two sorting conditions.  The first condition places matching product names first, and the second orders both matching/non-matching groups by the product name alphabetically.

```
SELECT productname
FROM products
ORDER BY productname LIKE '%biriyani%' DESC,
         productname
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle